# R: Quanteda: can I use textstat_keyness on two separate corpora?

Tags: r, quanteda

the usage of "textstat_keyness" is the following:

```
    textstat_keyness(x, target = 1L, measure = c("chi2", "exact", "lr", "pmi"), sort = TRUE, correction = c("default", "yates", "williams", "none"))
```

"target" is "the document index (numeric, character or logical) identifying the document forming the "target" for computing keyness; all other documents' feature frequencies will be combined for use as a reference" ([https://rdrr.io/cran/quanteda/man/textstat_keyness.html])

From the examples provided in the documentation, I understand that     textstat_keyness can only be applied to subparts of a single corpus (ie a single file), while I need to measure keyness in two separate corpora (ie two files).

Basically, I would like to measure keyness between a reference corpus ("x") and a specialized corpus ("target"). Reference corpus and specialized corpus are two distinct physical entities (two files having the same format). Is this possible to apply  textstat_keyness for this task?

Thanks in advance for your answer.
Kind Regards, 
Marina

Answer (score 2):

`textstat_keyness()` compares two partitions of a corpus to determine the words that are "key" or differentially occurring between the two partitions.  So for you to compare any target corpus to a baseline corpus, you would need to combine the two into a single dfm, and then specify the target appropriately.

Without your question being more specific, I will try to provide an example that I think provides what you want.  Here, I compare the keyness of words from the Irish Budget 2010 corpus, to the US presidents' inaugural address corpus (both built in to **quanteda**).

```
library("quanteda")
# Package version: 1.1.1

combinedcorp <- 
    corpus(c(texts(data_corpus_irishbudget2010), texts(data_corpus_inaugural)),
           docvars = data.frame(source = c(rep("irishbudget", ndoc(data_corpus_irishbudget2010)),
                                           rep("inaugural", ndoc(data_corpus_inaugural)))))
combinedcorp
# Corpus consisting of 72 documents and 1 docvar.

combineddfm <- dfm(combinedcorp, remove = stopwords("english"), remove_punct = TRUE)
```

In the next step, I have used `dfm_group()` to combine the documents into a two-"document" grouped dfm, prior to calling `textstat_keyness()`.  This is not really necessary, since `textstat_keyness()` can also automatically combine documents for a target index (and combines all others for the reference), but this gives you a bit more control, in case you want to select individual documents from the target category.  (You could do this by using matrix indexing `[` on the dfm, or `dfm_select()`, etc.)

```
keyn <- dfm_group(combineddfm, groups = "source") %>%
    textstat_keyness(target = "irishbudget")
```

Then we can clearly see which words were associated with the budget speeches, and which words were associated with the inaugural addresses.

```
rbind(head(keyn), tail(keyn))
#       feature       chi2 p n_target n_reference
# 1       budget  647.57319 0      260           6
# 2     minister  427.03308 0      170           3
# 3          tax  341.44085 0      163          20
# 4      billion  303.65819 0      119           1
# 5         jobs  264.91216 0      120          11
# 6      economy  236.90627 0      160          53
# 11377   nation  -89.30903 0       11         293
# 11378    peace  -93.77363 0        2         254
# 11379    great -103.21197 0       13         340
# 11380   states -113.18403 0        7         333
# 11381    shall -121.82532 0        0         314
# 11382     upon -136.96721 0        3         371
```